# Change Params with Rails after Checkbox is checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page that will display media that has already been uploaded to my website.  There will be 3 check boxes, one for each type of media, the check boxes are Images, catalog_images, and videos.  Once one is checked I want the page to reload the same page but add the check box to the parameters as being checked, so it will display the media(s) checked.

I'v been attempting to do it with javascript unsuccessfully.  I was hoping rails would have a built in function or something to help me out.  I will continue doing research and update this question if someone doesn't beat me to it.

Edit:  I had a request for code, which I didnt want to include just because it is in production already and has a lot of junk around it but i'll try to clean it up and give and idea of what im doing

```
<div class="panel">
    <h3>Create from Media</h3>
    <div>
        Image: <%= check_box_tag 'Catalog Image', :catalog_images %> | Images: <%= check_box_tag 'Images', :images %> | Video: <%= check_box_tag 'Videos', :videos %>
        <br />
        <% if @filenames %>
            <table class='list'>
                    <th>Lots</th>
                    <th>Sub Lot Creation</th>
           <% if :videos %>
              <% @videos.reject(&:blank?).uniq.each do |filename| %>
                    <% basename = File.basename(filename, '.*') %>

                    <tr>
                        <td><%= basename %></td>
                        <td><%= text_field_tag :low_range %> <%= text_field_tag :high_range %></td>
                    </tr>

            <% end %>
          <% end %>
   </table>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to "Create by Image", mass_create_from_media_admin_event_lots_path(@event, :images => true) %>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when each checkbox is tagged I want to reload and have :videos, :catalog_images, :images true if checked.  I know the validation isn't complete for each media, but I am also at home so I tried to quickly create a representation of what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you want to reload the page and append something like ?videos=checked to your url?

If that's the case you can do something like this (I suppose you're using jQuery, but you shouldn't have any problems rewriting this to coffee script):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    // your media type
    var mediaType = $(this).val();
    // set to true if checkbox has been checked, false otherwise
    var isChecked = ($(this).attr('checked')) == 'checked' ? true : false;

    if (isChecked == true) {
        // in case you already have some other params in your url
        if (currentUrl.indexOf('?') !== -1){
           currentUrl += '&' + mediaType ' + '=true';
        } else{
           currentUrl += '?' + mediaType ' + '=true';
        }
    }

    window.location.href = currentUrl;
});
```

I didn't run the code and you will need to solve some other use cases (e.g. what should happen when user unchecks the checkbox?)

Anyway this solution is kind of messy. I would suggest you to use either normal form with submit button or asynchronous call and change only that parts of the page that you need to.

Comment: yes this would work, but I think im going to go with your tip on using a form to ease the process of keeping track of the check boxes.  Thank you very much sometimes I just need another programmers input.